# Accumulate fields with same ID but different values

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi guys, I want to obtain the correct query to accumulated of field `cant prod`  taking into consideration that the `id_prod` number 22 appears two times  so I want it to appear in 2 rows: One with 21 as id_prod and 2.0000 in cant_prod, second with 22 as id_prod and 23.0000 in cant_prod

Comment: I THINK YOUR SHIFT KEY IS STUCK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sum() function:

```
SELECT id_prod, sum(cant_prod) as cant_prod from yourTable group by id_prod
```